# Cut out Nothing with foldl

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, option-type

I have a list [Maybe a] where I want to cut out the Nothing elements with a function that uses foldl
For example cut [Just 2, Just 10, Nothing, Just 5] -> [2,10,5]

```
I wrote:
cut :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
cut a = foldl (help) [] a
               where help (x:xs) Nothing = (x:xs)
                     help (x:xs) Just a = a:(x:xs)
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Why do you write `(x:xs)` in `help (x:xs)`.

Comment: What is going wrong? Does this compile? Can you give example output for example input?

Comment: Are you sure your homework doesn't say "`foldl` or `foldr`"? `foldl` is fundamentally the wrong approach here. Using it naturally would reverse the list.

Comment: I wrote (x:xs) because this is my list where I collect all Just elements.

Comment: @Bice: but `(x:xs)` does not restrict items to be a list (that will the type signature already do). It restrict things to be lists with *at least one element*.

Comment: @Bice You provide three arguments to `foldl`: `help`, `[]`, and `a`. The fact that `a` is explicitly declare to have type `[Maybe a]` means that `[] :: [a]` and `help :: [a] -> a -> [a]`. When you *define* `help`, you can't change that type; you can only write patterns (if needed) that *work* with that type.

Answer (score 3):

By writing `help (x:xs) Nothing = (x:xs)` you have used a pattern `(x:xs)` this means that you expect the accumulator to be a list with *at least* one element. But that is not always the case, for instance the initial accumulator `[]` is the empty list.

We can simply use a variable `l`, instead of a pattern:

```
cut :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
cut a = foldl help [] a
               where help l Nothing = l
                     help l (Just a) = a:l
```

Note that you also need to add brackets for a constructor with arguments.

But this will not solve the entire pattern, now you will have *reversed* the list. This is because `foldl` iterates through the list left-to-right, so you prepend values while you iterate through the list. We can use `foldr` instead. But now the type of the function does no longer works, since the `help` function in `foldr` takes the accumulator as second argument. So we can flip the arguments:

```
cut :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
cut a = foldr help [] a
               where help Nothing l = l
                     help (Just a) l = a:l
```

And now it works. We can however clean up the code a bit. For instance use an *eta*-reduction on the `cut` function: we can remove `a` in the head and body of the function:

```
cut :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
cut = foldr help []
               where help Nothing l = l
                     help (Just a) l = a:l
```

and since the second argument in `help` can be removed and the body converted into functions:

```
cut :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
cut = foldr help []
               where help Nothing = id
                     help (Just a) = (a:)
```

We can also use another catamorphism: `foldr` is the catamorphism of a list, and `maybe` is the catamorphism of `Maybe`, so we can write a:

```
maybe <value-in-case-of-nothing> <function-just-value> <Maybe value>
```

So we can rewrite our `help` to:

```
import Data.Maybe(maybe)

cut :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
cut = foldr help []
               where help = maybe id (:)
```

or simply inject it as an argument of `foldr`:

```
import Data.Maybe(maybe)

cut :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
cut = foldr (maybe id (:)) []
```

So now we used a *catamporhism* inside a *catamorphism*, so *catamorphception*.

Comment: You can go one step further and use `maybe` to define the helper: `foldr (maybe id (:)) []`.

Comment: @chepner: thanks. Now we constructed *catamorphception* :)